# External AsyncTask class with ProgressDialog [Update: and returning back?]

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

**Updated: (See below)**I have been looking around for couple of days and can't find a straight answer to this. 
Some say it possible to some say to accomplish some say it's not. I am getting crazy on this.

What I want is just to have the AsyncTaskTask showing a progressbar an external class. To do this I am passing the context as you can see in the main class. But whatever I try I get `NullPointerException`.

Working code examples is appreciated. Thank you

Using Android 2.2 by the way.

main:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class AsyncDemo extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new AsyncClass(this).execute();
    }
}
```

AsyncClass.java

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.SystemClock;

public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    private Context context;
    ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);

    public AsyncClass(Context cxt) {
        context = cxt;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
        SystemClock.sleep(2000);
        return (null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
 I have a follow up question: Using the above code, is it possible to return a value from the onPostExecute method back to the main class, somehow? (Sorry about beeing noobish)
I have tried something like this:

```
String result = new AsyncClass(this).execute();
```

and then a method that return back a string. But I can't do that because i got:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from AsyncTask<String,Void,Void> to String
```

What can I do to tackle this problem? Thanks.

Comment: I am interested in your follow up question. I have a similar situation and I am unsure how to get the return value back. What I am currently doing is I created a `field variable` and then I assign the result in `onPostExecute` but I am not sure if this is the correct way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were creating the `ProgressDialog` with a null context. The following code worked for me.

```
public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {
    private Context context;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

        public AsyncClass(Context cxt) {
            context = cxt;
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            dialog.setTitle("Please wait");
            dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
            SystemClock.sleep(2000);
            return (null);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that the ProcessDialog is instantiated before the constructor is called. Therefore context is null. Moving the instantiation of the ProcessDialog into the constructor like this ensures that context holds the value passed in cxt. Also, you don't realy need to store the context as a field in this sample. Just pass cxt to ProgressDialog constructor (i.e. dialog = new ProgressDialog(cxt)).

Answer (score 3):

ok this is what I did as i was using fragments. This is how you call the AsyncTask inside a fragment:

```
String result=new AsyncClass(getActivity()).execute();
```

and this is how my AsyncTask outer class looks like:

```
public class AsyncClass extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    ProgressDialog pdialog;

    public AsyncClass(Context context) {
        pdialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pdialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pdialog.setCancelable(false);
        pdialog.setTitle("Loading Feed..");
        pdialog.setMessage("Please wait.");pdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String result=null;
        //do your task here and generate result String
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(pdialog.isShowing())
             pdialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

@[SSZero](https://stackoverflow.com/users/400323/sszero) thanks great answer, helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to answer that follow up question i.e.

> I have a follow up question: Using the above code, is it possible to return a value from the onPostExecute method back to the main class, somehow? (Sorry about beeing noobish) I have tried something like this:
>
> `String result = new AsyncClass(this).execute();`

I did this in my code it worked.

```
AsyncClass ac=new AsyncClass();
                    
ac.execute("");

String rslt=ac.get();
```

Call this code wherever you want to.

```
public class AsynchClass extends AsyncTask <String,Integer,String>
{

    public String result=null;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
     
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
    {

            // Do all your background task here

            return result;
                    
    }
    @Override
     
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    
      
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    
    }
}
```