# Running ProgressDialog in Thread in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I want to run a ProgressDialog(Spinner) when I send and receive some packets in a bluetooth device when a button is pressed. Here is the code

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v) {


          Handler handler = new Handler();
          Runnable r=new Runnable()
          {
              public void run()
              {
                    dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(Test.this, "",
                           "Receiving. Please wait...", true);



              }
          };
          handler.post(r);

          blueToothServer.getDevicebyMac();
          blueToothServer.rfSocket();
          blueToothServer.cancelDiscovery();
          blueToothServer.connectSocket();
          //toastMessage("Socket connected");
          blueToothServer.ipstream();
          blueToothServer.opStream();
          blueToothServer.SendnRXDataToBTServer(2, "some String");
          String Result1 = blueToothServer.response(1);
          tv1.setText("Temperatue : " + Result1);
          dialog1.dismiss();
 }
```

But I'm not getting the ProgressDialog. But I can able to send and receive the packets. But when I comment the blueToothServer operations, I'm getting the progress dialog. Please explain me the situation where I can get both. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be showing the `ProgressDialog` in the UI thread and executing the bluetooth operations in a background thread.  It is exactly for this purpose, the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) is provided.

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3347405/1321873