# Android: ProgressDialog in external async class (sth block async thread)

Tags: android, asynchronous, android-asynctask, external, progressdialog

I have main activity:

```
public class ChooseWriteSentenceActivity extends ActionBarActivity{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        String userName = "Zdzisiu";
        String password = "Ziemniak";
        MainServie service = new MainService(this);
        boolean isExsist = service.findUser(String userName, String password);
        //more code...
    }   
}
```

In my app service uses repositories and jsonconsumers but for simpler code I'm skipping them.

```
public class MyService{
    private Context context;
    public MyService(Context context){
        this.context = context
    }
    public boolean findUser(String userName, String password){
        String resultS = null;
        try{
            resultS = new QueryExecutorFindUser(context).execute(userName,password).get();
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        boolean realRes = jsonConsumer(resultS).getFindUser();
        return realRes;
    }
}

public class QueryExecutorFindUser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {


protected final String connectionUrl = "http://myWebService:44302/Service.svc/";

    protected ProgressDialog progressDialog; 
    protected Context curContext;

    public QueryExecutor(Context context){
        curContext = context;
    }

    @Override  
    protected void onPreExecute()  
    {  
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(curContext,"Loading...",  
                "Loading application View, please wait...", false, false);  
    }

    @Override  
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)  
    {  
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        progressDialog.dismiss();   
    } 

    protected String doInBackground(String... args){
        String result = null;
        String url = connectionUrl + args[0] + "/" + args[1];
        HttpResponse response = null;
        HttpClient httpclient =  this.getNewHttpClient();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        get.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); 
        get.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json"); 
        try{
            response = httpclient.execute(get);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                if(response != null){
                    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
                    out.close();
                    result = out.toString();
                }
            } else{
                throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
            }
        } catch(Exception ex){
            ex.getMessage();
        } finally{
            if(response != null){
                try{
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                } catch(Exception ex){
                }
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

And progress dialog is show but only after all code in onCreatre in ChooseWriteSentenceActivity including doInBacground(...) from QueryExecutor is finished (so it disappears practically at the same time). It looks like sth waiting for thread with QueryExecutorFindUser.doInBackground()  and it is runs like synchronously (?), I think that because when I debug code  onPreExecute() is running correctly (and start before doInBackground(...)) and progressDialog.isShowing() == true (but not on the screen :( ).

If I remove extends AsyncTask from QueryExecutorFindUser and make private class with this extension in main activity (and run all code from onCreated() including service.findUser() in thisPrivateClass.doInBackground(...)) it works okey.

I prefer to have progressDialog in one place no in all main activities (of cource in practise I use QueryExecutor for all queries not only findUser) but I don't have idea what i am doing wrong. I spent all day on it with no result :(

Comment: try to start the progress dialog in the onCreate instead of onPre

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialogs are tied to an `Activity` and ultimately must be hosted by one. So until your app's activity gets created, the dialog will not display.

Comment: Okey I understand, so it's only possible when Activity run directly async thread. In my example new thread is running from new object - instance of this object is blocked created activity, right? Is that the reason why my code doesn't work and this one works okey: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347247/external-asynctask-class-with-progressdialog-update-and-returning-back   ???

Comment: What is `jsonConsumer` and what is `out` in the `doInBackground()`?  You have a lot of things chained together here and if the jsonConsumer is somehow blocking, you are preventing the UI thread from continuing so your `Activity` is not proceeding to a running state so the dialog won't be shown.